# Cassandra - User defined data type

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have tried Cassandra user defined data type [example given by DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/crudOperations.html) and I'm getting the below exception.
They did not specify how `Address` object should look like for this case. I have defined UDT type but it doesn't help.
Can any one help me how the Address class should look like?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot map unknown class com.att.opus.mytest.Address for field private com.att.opus.mytest.Address com.att.opus.mytest.Account.address
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper.getSimpleType(ReflectionMapper.java:321)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper.extractType(ReflectionMapper.java:286)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper$LiteralMapper.<init>(ReflectionMapper.java:65)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper$LiteralMapper.<init>(ReflectionMapper.java:59)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.ReflectionMapper$ReflectionFactory.createColumnMapper(ReflectionMapper.java:372)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.convert(AnnotationParser.java:154)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.parseEntity(AnnotationParser.java:103)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.getMapper(MappingManager.java:119)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.mapper(MappingManager.java:76)
    at com.att.opus.mytest.AccountMapper.test(AccountMapper.java:12)
    at com.att.poc.Main.accountTest(Main.java:53)
    at com.att.poc.Main.main(Main.java:40)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it the problem still persists, but it seems that Your Address class should be annotated with @UDT annotation, as described [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/mappingUdts.html)